# Emacs code hints in minibuffer. How do I get them?

Tags: emacs, code-hinting

I've looked all over the internet for this, and since I'm new to Emacs, I don't know what to search for. I'm not looking for mini-buffer completion for commands and such. I'm looking for code hints in the mini-buffer, as shown in this gif. I couldn't care less about the fancy parens, the code hints are awesome. How do I get them?

[image: Completion]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need <kbd>M-x</kbd> `eldoc-mode`. It's enabled by default in 24.5.

Comment: Cool, now how do I make that a default for elisp buffers, apparently it's not a default in the version I have. In other words, how do I circumvent having to press M-x eldoc-mode?

Comment: Look at the commentary at the beginning of the `eldoc` library file (`M-x find-library RET eldoc RET`).